# IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j

spring boot starter 1.5.1.RELEASE getting an error.am integrated web, jpa dev tools modules, and using STS. org.springframework 4.3.6.RELEASE.
 thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService.<init>(RelaxedConversionService.java:52)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:148)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
at com.in.gov.cgg.tspsckeyobj.TspscKeyObjApplication.main(TspscKeyObjApplication.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)  java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: declaredFieldsCache
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.clear(Restarter.java:366)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.cleanupKnownCaches(Restarter.java:349)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.cleanupCaches(Restarter.java:338)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.access$000(Restarter.java:84)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:175)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:170)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$LeakSafeThread.run(Restarter.java:627)
```

pom.xml  [excluding some extra dependencies which are im using specific perpose ] -->>

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: if you comment devtools dependecy, will work it, right?

Comment: No. Not working still getting `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters`      thaks for replay @JonathanJohx

Comment: OK then is exclusion org.slf4j ... please comment it this and let me know what happens

Comment: removed exclusion of org.slf4j. but still same error.

Comment: OK I read the error message and you need to upgrade your spring to 4.3.7 and your problem will be solved.